# YouTube player shrinks in fullscreen

Tags: macos, safari, youtube

When I am watching YouTube on my Mac, sometimes when I'm in fullscreen it'll shrink the video to 1/4 of the screen, nested in the top-right corner. What causes this?

MacBook Pro 2016 13" Touchbar model
macOS 10.12.4 (16E195)
Using Safari

Comment: Have you tried to see if the symptoms are present in different browsers like  Chrome or Firefox?

Comment: @Allan no- it is infrequent but I will use these browsers over the next few days and see if anything changes.